# Jquery Event not triggering when selector is a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have following selector

```
    jQuery("table[class='google-visualization-table-table']").on("click", "tr", function(){alert('i am here'); }
```

I am creating table using GOOGLE API

Following is my HTML

```
<table class="google-visualization-table-table" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-head">
<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even">
<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-odd">
<td class="google-visualization-table-td">MONTEFIORE MEDICAL CENTER</td>
<td class="google-visualization-table-td">208604209.00</td>
<td class="google-visualization-table-td">666813000.00</td>
<td class="google-visualization-table-td">68.72</td>
<td class="google-visualization-table-td">31.28</td>
</tr>
<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even">
<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-odd">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this table being added dynamically?

Comment: yes, its added dynamically

Comment: Use event delegation. Bind the event handler on body, or any parent element that exists on dom ready...

Comment: A performance hint: The shorter a selector is, the faster the element is selected. Additionally an attribute selector is slower than a class selector. So instead of `table[class='google-visualization-table-table']` maybe just use `.google-visualization-table-table`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems these elements are generated dynamically by GOOGLE API.  So bind it with document

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "table.google-visualization-table-table tr", function(){
    alert('i am here'); 
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

**jQuery Selectors**

**CLASS** - `$(".class")`

**ID** - `$("#id")`

**HTML TAG** - `$("tag")`

and you can also combine the selectors, e.g. `$("tag.class")`

---

Now if the element is already not there on the page use **event delegation** binding

```
$(parent-selector).on(event,target-selector,callback);
```

In your case :

```
$(document).on("click", "table.google-visualization-table-table", function(){
    alert('i am here'); 
});
```

***Note:** The parent-selector must be parent element which is present in the DOM while binding the event, generally people use `document` and `body`, but for the performance you must have the **nearest parent possible** to the target*

Answer (score 3):

That code will work *provided* that the table exists when you run the code (see below) (and provided you have this missing `);` at the end in your real code). It's fragile, though, and I wouldn't recommend it. I'd use a class selector instead, e.g.

```
table.google-visualization-table-table
```

not

```
table[class='google-visualization-table-table']
```

Because the latter will break if you add any other classes to the table.

So two options:

1. Don't run that line of code until *after* you create the table.
2. Go further with your event delegation, hooking `click` on whatever container you're adding the table to, like this:

   ```
   jQuery("some container").on("click", "table.google-visualization-table-table tr", function(){alert('i am here'); });
   ```

   Just make sure the container exists when you run that. As a **last** resort, use `jQuery (document)`, but there's almost always a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation. Depending on the version of jQuery you are using, there are different ways to do this. Assuming your version is fairly new, Bind click event to a body then delegate it to table.google-visualization-table-table tr. Or you could also instead of body, bind the event handler to a parent element of table.google-visualization-table-table, that exists on dom ready.

```
$('body').on("click", "table.google-visualization-table-table tr", function(){
   alert('i am here'); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "table.google-visualization-table-table tr", function(){
   alert('i am here'); 
});
```

This will work for all a tags `tr` in the `table`, whether already present or dynamically added later.

Comment: is there a way to use table as a part of selector, ah u edited it

Comment: "try this" followed by a code dump is not useful. Say *what* you changed, and *why*. *(not my dv)*

Answer (score 0):

This is your code....

```
jQuery("table[class='google-visualization-table-table']").on("click", "tr", function () { alert('i am here'); }
```

And you are missing just ending breakets **");"**

please se my updated code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("table[class='google-visualization-table-table']").on("click", "tr", function () { alert('i am here'); });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

this should work better with jquery you use the # for ids and . for classes and just the tag name.

```
$(".table.google-visualization-table-table > table").on("click", "tr", function(){
   alert('i am here'); 
});
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

and other than that learning about css selectors the > will select all child table elements of that class.